# How to filter one date column by weeks?

Tags: python, pandas

There is a problem - I created a table with dates for couple of years, and now i need to filter it by weeks (to work only with with first days of every week), but no matter how i try it doesn't work. Will be glad if you'll help me.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Date":pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='31/12/2019')}) 
weeks = pd.date_range(df1['Date'].min(), df1['Date'].max(), freq ='W')
df1[weeks]
```

I could convert it into pd.DataFrame but then it won't give an error but instead it gives NaT in all rows.

Comment: What is the first day of a week? Sunday or Monday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it easily just by selecting all the Mondays:

```
df1[lambda x: x["Date"].dt.day_name() == "Monday"]

          Date
0   2018-01-01
7   2018-01-08
14  2018-01-15
21  2018-01-22
28  2018-01-29
..         ...
700 2019-12-02
707 2019-12-09
714 2019-12-16
721 2019-12-23
728 2019-12-30
```

Comment: `df1[df1.Date.dt.day_of_week.eq(0)]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dt` accessor and `dayofweek`:

```
# 6 -> Sunday, 0 -> Monday
>>> df1[df1['Date'].dt.dayofweek == 0]

          Date
0   2018-01-01
7   2018-01-08
14  2018-01-15
21  2018-01-22
28  2018-01-29
..         ...
700 2019-12-02
707 2019-12-09
714 2019-12-16
721 2019-12-23
728 2019-12-30

[105 rows x 1 columns]
```